# 500 error occurs on AI HUB in GCP while using "Open in GCP" and "Download"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]I can't create an instance on GCP using AI HUB assets.
While using **"Open in GCP"** and **"Download"**, **500 error** occurs.
(Ex. asset name is "Building, training, and deploying XGBoost model using Kubeflow Fairing")
I logged out of GCP and logged in again, but the error didn't go away.
How can I resolve this problem?
Help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you share the full error message from the logs?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I shared the image"500 error" above, so please check it.
Thanks.

Comment: The engineering team is aware of this issue, as a workaround you can use the [Cloud AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs). In addition, I have opened a public issue tracker case so you can keep track of any updates, [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176151497). Did it help you?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will keep track of it.

Comment: in order to further contribute to the community I have added an answer with the information I shared with you. Please, if you found the information useful consider accepting and upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engineering team is aware of this issue. I have opened a public issue tracker case, in order to for you to keep track of any updates, here.

Currently, as a work around you can use the [Cloud AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs).